# liverserver.so cannot open. uv4l mjpegstream

Tags: raspberry-pi, rtsp, mjpeg, v4l2, uv4l

I'm having issues making a virtual camera with uv4l mjpegstream.
This mjpegstream is not a camera but rather a graphic that I created.

```
pi@iot:~ $uv4l --driver mjpegstream --auto-video_nr --verbosity=8 -f --uri "http://10.1.7.191/api/gfx/stream.jpg" --server-option=--port=80
<notice> [core] Trying to loading driver 'mjpegstream' from built-in drivers...
<notice> [core] Loading driver 'mjpegstream' from external plug-in's...
<info> [driver] Specified URI:
        URI: http://10.1.7.191/api/gfx/stream.jpg
        UserInfo:
        Scheme: http
        Host: 10.1.7.191
        Port: 80
        Path: /api/gfx/stream.jpg
        Query:
<notice> [core] Device detected!
<notice> [core] Trying to load the the Streaming Server plug-in...
<warning> [core] libserver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
<warning> [core] Continuing without Streaming Server...
<notice> [core] Registering device node /dev/video0

pi@iot:~ $ dd if=/dev/video0 of=snapshot.jpeg bs=11M count=1
dd: failed to open '/dev/video0': Input/output error
```

The whole reason for me doing this is to convert the mjpeg stream to rtsp.
I believe I should be able to do this pretty easily. But it seems there are issues with my implementation
https://kevinsaye.wordpress.com/2018/10/17/making-a-rtsp-server-out-of-a-raspberry-pi-in-15-minutes-or-less/
If anyone knows of a better more efficient way to do this please let me know

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Forgot to install uv4l-server. ‍♂️

<sup>Yall could of let me know instead of downvotng me :(</sup>

This comment helped me out the most

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve/99626#99626

Answer (score -1):

Just `apt-get install uv4l-mjpegstream`